# $\operatorname{Hom}_A(A^*, P)\cong P$ such that $P$ is projective under the given assumption?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a field $k$. Let $A^* = \operatorname{Hom}_k (A,k)$ and $A^*$ is $A$-bimodule. Suppose that $\operatorname{Hom}_A (A^*, A) \cong A$ as left $A$-module. Then is it true that $\operatorname{Hom}_A(A^*, P)\cong P$ such that $P$ is projective?

Comment: Could you maybe give a little more details? Is $k$ a field? What is $A$ exactly? Is it any $k$-algebra? What $A$-module structure do you use on $A^*$ (on the left, on the right, etc.)?

Comment: I edited the question by considering your questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A^*$ is finite dimensional as a $k$-vector space, then $A^*$ is finitely generated both as a left and as a right $A$-module.

In particular we can state that
$$
\textstyle\operatorname{Hom}_A(A^*,\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I}M_i)\cong
\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I}\operatorname{Hom}_A(A^*,M_i)
$$
for any index set $I$ and any family of $A$-modules. If we denote by $A^{(I)}$ a direct sum of copies of $A$, we get
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_A(A^*,A^{(I)})\cong\bigl(\operatorname{Hom}_A(A^*,A)\bigr){}^{(I)}
$$
so your statement is true for every free $A$-module. If $P$ is projective, then $P\oplus P'$ is free, for some module $P'$.

Comment: Thank you very much! So does it mean that $Hom_A(A^*,P) \cong P$ such that P is projective?

Comment: @Mathalg Yes, you just have to finish up the argument.